# facing permission denied issue after integrating Authorization module to Function App

Tags: azure

i m facing Issue the Azure function App
I am with every possible way to make function App work using Token that I was able to generate with. 
I am facing issue "You do not have permission to view this directory or page."
I have successfully generated token using

Answer (score 0):

Could you please provide more information so that we can help you with? How are you trying to call the function. Are you trying to change the Authentication/Authorisation option under Platform features?

Best Regards,
Suraj Revankar

Answer (score 0):

I have followed below steps for adding authentication to function App

-- Created a function app with Anonymous level function 
-- Go to platform features for the same and selected option as "login with azure directory"
-- Select express option under Azure active directory settings

-- on the other tab, I created an azure directory
-- Created Secret keys and copy application id for the same
-- Added required permissions and grant them too.

-- then on the prevoius tab under function app I selected this direcory app.
-- Using POSTMAN, I was able to generate the token.
-- But on the next request for function app response, when I am using this token as authorization bearer, its showing me "You do not have access for this directory" error